# redirecting thread group in every x sec in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to check in `If` controller of Jmeter whether the elapsed time is greater than  x seconds. For that, I created a timer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820033/make-a-simple-timer-in-java/14323134) using `System.CurrentTimeMillis` and put it in a preProcessor

```
        boolean x=true;
        long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
          
        while(x){

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        long timepassed=System.currentTimeMillis()-starttime;
        long secondspassed=timepassed/1000;
        if(secondspassed==3)
        {
            secondspassed=0;
            starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(displayMinutes+"::"+secondspassed);
        }
       
        
     }
```

But when I am running jmeter test plan, it is looping within timer and logging every 3 secs but not proceeding further with other steps in thread group

I tried to utilize jmeter `constant timer` but it is pausing the whole thread group for x seconds.

What I would like is that thread group continues with steps inside it and while thread group is making requests , at every x secs thread should set a jmeter property that is checked in `If` controller ,which will redirect it to a different thread group for token generation and then back again to this thread.

I was trying to create a timer so I can get handle of every x secs and then use that logic to set a property flag .

How can I achieve this in jmeter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above approach didn't work somehow for me. What worked was , in a JSR223 preprocessor , I put this and choose groovy as language

```
def st = new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){  
   if (props.getProperty("myProp").equals("")){ 
   def et = st+ 10.seconds
   props.put("myProp", et.getTime() as String)
}

}
```

and below in same thread in a `IF` controller

```
${_groovy(Long.valueOf(props.get("myProp"))-(new Date().getTime())<=0,)}
```

and inside `IF` controller in JSR223 sampler put this

`props.put("myProp","")`

Then in a `Module` controller , under `IF`, you can redirect where you like .
I redirected to an `IF` controller in a different thread and used `Flow Control Action` (start next thread loop option)within this `IF` to redirect back to original thread

and at the start of the test plan mark property as blank like `props.put("myProp","")`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is doing this in a separate Thread Group like you did when you "tried to utilize jmeter `constant timer`"

This Thread Group would consist of:

1. [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) configured to pause for 3000 milliseconds
2. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   props.put('your-property-name', 'your-property-value')
   ```

This way the second Thread Group will set a property each 3 seconds which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Under your If Controller you can reset or remove the property so the If Controller would stop firing:

```
props.remove('your-property-name') // removes the property
props.put('your-property-name', 'some-other-value') // overwrites previous value
```

In the above code snippets `props` stands for the instance of [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn more about this and other JMeter API shortcuts, in this `props` object JMeter keeps all its properties including user-defined ones and [properties are global for all Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (and in fact to the whole JVM)

Comment: I added TG2 above TG1 (main thread that sends request). TG2 has only two steps that you mentioned and `constant timer` step is above JSR223 step in TG2.  I am checking property flag just before `If` controller in TG1 , but its printing null.  TG1 loop count is set to infinite. For `If` controller this is my groovy to check `${_groovy(props.getProperty("flag").equals("true"))}` .  Do you see anything missing ?

Comment: I noticed that I added JSR223 preprocessor but now I have added JSR223 sampler as you suggested. When I run ,  this thread  i.e TG2 keeps on executing every x secs and do not proceed to next thread. How can I make it proceed to next thread while it executes every x secs to set property ?